# How to get the binary of a double in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For a char or int, I can do this:

```
void print2(char c)//print char c in binary
{
    for(int i=7;i>=0;i--)
        if ((1<<i)&c) printf("1");
        else printf("0");
}
```

But for double I can't use operator &.

And I can't use reinterpret_cast(It's C++).

Then, How to do that?

Comment: `memcpy` it to a `unsigned char[sizeof (double)]`.

Comment: memcpy? I never knew it. Sounds interesting. @DanielFischer Thanks.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I've misinterpreted "And I can't use reinterpret_cast(It's C++).". You're working in C, then using a union is simpler (less code) than `memcpy`. If you can `assert(sizeof (double) == sizeof(uint64_t))`, I'd suggest a `union pun { double d; uint64_t u; };`, otherwise using an `unsigned char[sizeof (double)]` in the union would be an option.

Comment: @DanielFischer Plus: you would need to add an `assert (sizeof(double) == sizeof(unsigned long long))` somehere. IMHO the memcpy to char[sizeof(double)] is more flexible wrt portability. (especially if stdint.h is not available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive implementation with `memcpy()`, as per @Daniel Fischer's comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

void double_to_bits(double val);

int main(void)
{
unsigned idx;

double vals[] = { -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };

for (idx = 0; idx < 4; idx++ ) {
        printf("\nvals[%u]= %+lf-->>", idx, vals[idx] );
        double_to_bits(vals[idx] );
        }
printf("\n");

return 0;
}

void double_to_bits(double val)
{
unsigned idx;
unsigned char arr[sizeof val];

memcpy (arr, &val, sizeof val);

for (idx=CHAR_BIT * sizeof val; idx-- ; ) {
        putc(
        ( arr[idx/CHAR_BIT] & (1u << (idx%CHAR_BIT) ) )
        ? '1'
        : '0'
        , stdout
        );
        }
}
```

, and the same with a pointer (omitting the char array and the memcpy)

```
void double_to_bits2(double val)
{
unsigned idx;
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*) &val;

for (idx=CHAR_BIT * sizeof val; idx-- ; ) {
        putc(
        ( ptr[idx/CHAR_BIT] & (1u << (idx%CHAR_BIT) ) )
        ? '1'
        : '0'
        , stdout
        );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `union` rather than `memcpy` or `pointer`:

```
void print2(double x)//print double x in binary
{
    union {
        double x;
        char c[sizeof(double)];
    } u;

    assert(sizeof(char) == 1);

    u.x = x;

    for (unsigned ofs = 0; ofs < sizeof(double); ofs++) {
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
            printf(((1 << i) & u.c[ofs]) ? "1" : "0");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL@ `assert(sizeof(char) == 1);` Priceless!

Comment: Priceless, indeed. What was the point of that?

Comment: Reminder to future readers looking for a C++ version: union type-punning is safe in C, but not ISO C++.  (Some mainstream C++ compilers also define the behaviour, including GCC/Clang and MSVC, but there are some that don't.)  `memcpy` works the same in both languages.  Modern C++ should use `std::bit_cast<uint64_t>`.  (Or maybe to a struct with an `unsigned char [8]` member if you the bytes in endian-dependent order like this code prints.  `unsigned char*` can alias anything so you can actually skip the union/memcpy for that.)

Comment: Also, this answer should probably be using `unsigned char`; on systems where `char` is signed, it relies on sign-extension to `int` to keep bit #7 unchanged for negative chars.  A sign/magnitude C implementation wouldn't do that, e.g. the `0x81` bit-pattern represents negative one, and a 32-bit `int` representing the same value has bit-pattern `0x80000001`.  (Sign bit moves instead of being copied the way 2's complement does.) And negative-zero (`0x80`) might be a trap representation (at least for int) or might extend to +0

Answer (score 2):

Presuming a `double` has 64 bits, this reinterprets the bytes of a `double x` as an unsigned 64-bit integer:

```
(union { double d; uint64_t u; }) {x} .u;
```

This is legal C, with the bytes of the `double` being implementation-dependent. It defines a compound literal that is a union, initializes the union with the `double`, and accesses the `uint64_t` member. The C standard says that when a member other than the last-stored member is accessed, the bytes are reinterpreted as the new type.

Answer (score 1):

Create char pointer and make it point to this double. Print first sizeof(double) chars using your function.

Comment: You want `unsigned char*`, but yes, this is actually safe in terms of strict-aliasing.  If you want the bytes of the `double` in an endian-dependent order, rather than least-significant first, you don't need `memcpy` or a `union`.